# LinkedIn not valid XML response

Tags: xml, api, linkedin-api

I get an error response from the API as follows:

```
<error>
  <status>400</status>
  <timestamp>1423663594219</timestamp>
  <request-id>SH8SLPTSPN</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>&#39;submitted-image-url&#39;: Description needs to be a valid URL</message>
</error>
```

The problem is that after converting this code in SimpleXML Object I can not get access to the property "error-code":

```
VarDumper::dump($xml->error-code);
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for me:

```
$xml = preg_replace('/([<\/]\w*)-(\w*[>])/', '$1$2', $data['linkedin']);
```

Removing all dashes from parameters names.